# Camel: Mock a processor to test Route

Tags: java, unit-testing, apache-camel, mockito

I am trying to create a unit test for the routing.
I have the following route configuration

```
from ("direct:getA")
    .routeId("get-a").startupOrder(1)
    .process(exchange -> {
        QueryObject queryObject = exchange.getIn().getBody(QueryObject.class);
        exchange.getIn().setHeader(foo, queryObject.getH());
        exchange.setOut(exchange.getIn());
    })
    .choice()
        .when(header(foo).isEqualTo(fooConstant.bar))
            .process("barProcessor")
        .when(header(foo).isEqualTo(fooConstant.bie))
            .process("bieProcessor")
    .end();
```

My question is, how can I mock "barProcessor" and "bieProcessor"?

I tried to use adviceWith but I could not retrieve the routeDefinition. The context.getRouteDefinitions() returns an empty list.

**Edit:**
Below is the code snippet from my test.

```
RouteDefinition routeDef = context.getRouteDefinition("get-a");
routeDef.adviceWith(context, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            interceptSendToEndpoint("*barProcessor*").process(
                    new Processor() {
                        @Override
                        public void process(Exchange exchange) {
                            System.out.println("bar");
                        }
                    }
            );
            interceptSendToEndpoint("*bieProcessor*").process(
                    new Processor() {
                        @Override
                        public void process(Exchange exchange) {
                            System.out.println("Bie");
                        }
                    }
            );
        }
    });

String request = <JSON Request>;
websocket.sendTest(request);
```

But the `context.getRouteDefinition("get-a");` is returning null. And when I also used `context.getRouteDefinitions()`, it returns an empty list.

Comment: show us what you did.. also what exactly that case should do.. there is lot of going on there

Comment: @MaciejKowalski See my edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of this issue.
I forgot to Override the createRouteBuilder and createJndiContext.

```
@Override
protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() {
    return new SampleRoute(<param>);
}

@Override
protected JndiContext createJndiContext() throws Exception {
    JndiContext context = new JndiContext();
    context.bind("barProcessor", new BarProcessor());
    context.bind("bieProcessor", new BieProcessor());
    return context;
}
```

I found the solution from this link: [Unit Test](https://dzone.com/articles/correctly-using-apache-camel)